# .NET detect application exit from a library

Tags: c#, .net

I'm currently building a .NET 5.0 class library with some objects that require starting its own threads. The issue I ran into is that if user creates these objects (for example, from a WinForms application) and forgets to dispose these, its threads will just continue running. I tried:

1. Handling `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ProcessExit` event;
2. Implementing a finalizer.

Unfortunately none of these solutions worked.

Is there any way to ensure termination of these threads without user calling `Dispose()`?

**UPD:**
Threads I create should do work indefinitely in a loop like:

```
void MainThread()
{
    while (!shouldExit)
    {
        DoSomeWork();
    }
}
```

Therefore, interrupting the thread is not a problem, problem is detecting when I should do it.

Comment: Do the objects your library creates truly require *dedicated threads* that you create and manage?  What I mean is are you sure it could the asynchronous work they need to be done could not be `Task.Run` based work?

Comment: You can set the `IsBackground` property of the threads to ensure they don't hold up process exit. If the threads are not under your control, the only thing you can do is call `Environment.Exit` to rudely end their lives along with the process.

Comment: @Joe, unfortunately, one-time `Task`s won't suffice. It should be a thread which does its job even without any interaction with user.

Comment: as @Joe suggests, use `Task.Run()` instead. There is nothing you can't do with `Task` you are doing with `Thread`. `Task` methods are smarter than `Thread` and they will work with threads in a most efficient way, you won't need to think about how threads are returning back to the thread pool etc

Comment: @JeroenMostert, `IsBackground` property does the trick perfectly, thank you!

Comment: @OlegI, added an explanation to the question why it's not the case. But, as I mentioned, setting `IsBackground` to `true` is exactly what I needed.